# Ajax search on click with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, submit

This is the code i am currently using for my auto complete search for an input box.  I have tried multiple times to get it to search or submit the search when you click on what automatically pops up. Please help I have tried everything

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        SearchText();
    });
    function SearchText() {
        $(".autosuggest").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "/test.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                    data: "{'PartNumber':'" + document.getElementById('txtPartNum').value + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert(err.message);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is the code after attempting to add the submit/enter click function.

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        SearchText();
    });
    function SearchText() {
        $(".autosuggest").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "/test.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                    data: "{'PartNumber':'" + document.getElementById('txtPartNum').value + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert(err.message);
                         },
                        select: function(event, ui) {

                         $("#searchform button").click(); 
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: did you see any errors in your browser console ?

Comment: 500 - Internal server error.

Comment: So you are not able to hit your webmethod. Check your url option of $.ajax